# Android app theme - difference when using theme from style xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

Why is there a difference between theme defined in AndroidManifest.xml and theme taken from styles.xml?

1) AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
```

2) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application ... android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
</resources>
```

1st setting gives black theme and no action bar. 2nd has dark action bar and light menu.

**EDIT :** options 1) and 2) - notice Menu and ActionBar

[image] [image]

**EDIT 2:**

**Why doesn't the 2nd option actually use the AppTheme (Theme.Black) ?** (tested on SGS3)

Comment: Actually there is no difference, because you are only renaming the theme in the AppTheme or putting the theme in the Manifest file. However, the AppTheme in the manifest is the default.

Comment: You should not get different visuals. Are you sure you don't have any other res/values folder like res/values-v11, res/values-v14, res/values-anything, etc, that contain a theme.xml which define another parent for @style/AppTheme ?

Answer (score 9):

You probably have another `styles.xml` file, perhaps under a directory like "values-v11", that is defining the `@style/AppTheme` differently than `@android:style/Theme.Black` and taking precedence over the file you're viewing/modifying.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my issue! I had a "values/styles.xml" and a "values-v21/styles.xml". I removed the code `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style>` from the file "values-v21/styles.xml" and everything worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

`@android:style/Theme.Black` implements the exact theme implemented by Android (or device manufacturer). However, `@style/AppTheme` allows you to perform custom modification in your theme which actually extends the original *Theme.Black* from android, and in order to perform custom modifications, you use style resources.

In simple words, its just like using *Activity* class or *YourOwnActivity* class which extends *Activity* with extra features inside.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why there is a difference between the above examples, since I've made no additional modifications and only "extend" the default `Theme.Black`? I thought that without any modifications my `AppTheme` should be the same as `@android:style/Theme.Black`. Maybe it should be like this, but I just don't get it why :)

Comment: What difference are you talking about? is it visual? can you include the screen-shots for both styles?

Comment: are you using the same device? or two different devices?

Comment: one screen shot seems to use ordinary style with no action-bar and the other seems to use Holo with action-bar. Are you sure these are the only styles defined and in-use in your activity?

Comment: Yes, I just realized it actually seems like the parent doesn't work. I can write any other theme there and it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Styles.xml enables you to create your own themes. In AndroidManifest, you set the theme you want for an app or activity. You may want to use a system theme or your own. You can also extend other themes as you're doing setting "parent" attribute. For further information, check this out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" />
</resources>
```

in a xml file called `res/themes.xml`